# framework not found Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, flutter, onesignal

I use OneSignal for push notification in Flutter. I can build it on devices and simulator but has the errors when archiving.

`ld: framework not found Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension`

Comment: I already found the solution for this problem. I've set my iOS target for my project to iOS 12 and use `platform :ios, '12.0'` in my Podfile. So I changed my OneSignalNotifcationServiceExtension iOS target to iOS12 too instead of iOS 10 as suggested and it works like charm.

Comment: This!!!!  Targeted 10.0 like the tutorial said, changed it to 11.0 to match and it worked a treat.  Thanks.

Comment: They really should fix the tutorial so this problem doesn't happen to more people -- also for me this issue only occurred when I attempted to archive my app to submit to apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already found the solution for this problem. I've set my iOS target for my project to iOS 12 and use platform :ios, '12.0' in my Podfile. So I changed my OneSignalNotifcationServiceExtension iOS target to iOS12 too instead of iOS 10 as suggested and it works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue in another way.

1. close xcode project
2. go to Android Studio
3. flutter clean
4. flutter pub get
5. flutter build ios
6. open Runner.xcoworkspace

done.